# direct google drive api download link with original file name

Tags: api, file, download, space, drive

Good day

My problem i added the google drive api to get for files larger than 100mb no virus warning message from google drive
without google api its like this warning after clicking the link
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1DyXunnAetC9Xc8Ur0poTmLWo7Yo3DylZ

i want the download without that warning message i mean a direct download
so i created an api and created an direct download link over this site
https://www.wonderplugin.com/online-tools/google-drive-direct-link-generator/

what i get is this
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/11KPre5Rr3i9jqUr2QdlS-98Kl4wuaW6Z?alt=media&key=AIzaSyBybF13v7u-zXnruCs6uJ9I1QxoDFe0miw

it works correctly the warning message is bypassed but the name of the file is also changed to the file id this would look for customers of my cloud really scary like a virus and not like a apk file or something

so what i want is that the file name will be displayed by downloading and not something crazy like 037eugd98zr9u2dßih9ud237
without api the warning apears but the download file has the file name and not the ß30ru329fie2hfe crazy name :D

can someone help me?